# Approximation of the length of a number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, approximation

Consider a positive integer number $2^{{10}^n}$ where $n\geq 5$.

*Question:* How to prove the length of  the number $2^{{10}^n}$ is equal to
$30103{\underbrace{00\cdots0}_{n-5}}$.

*Example:* Consider $n=6$ then we have
$$
2^{{10}^6}=990065622929589825069792361\cdots 71236104888403162747109376
$$

It can be checked that the length of $2^{{10}^6}$ is $301030$.

*Try:*

Consider the following approximation 
$$
2^{10}=1024 \approx 10^3 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 2^{10^n} \approx 10^{3\times10^{n-1}} 
$$

It is easy to check that the length of $10^{3\times10^{n-1}}$ is equal to 
$3{\underbrace{00\cdots0}_{n-1}}$.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: consider logarithm base $10$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You method is correct. But I would like to prove from the mentioned try in question. Thanks

Comment: $2^{100000}\approx10^{30103}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Good point you mentioned. Please post it as a an answer and complete it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of digits in a positive integer $n$ is $\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1.$

$0.30102<\log_{10} 2<0.30103$

so $30102<\log_{10} 2^{100000} < 30103;\quad$  i.e., $2^{100000}\approx{10^{30103}}.$

Therefore, the number of digits in $2^{100000}$ is $30103$.

However, actually $\log_{10} 2= 0.30102999566...,$ so the number of digits in $2^{10^9}$ is $301029996,$

not $301030000$ as you thought.